# Pre-request scripts in Paw

Tags: paw-app

I want to calculate MD5 hash from all query parameters, sorted alphabetically before a request is made.

In Postman it could be done by:

```js
var params = [];

pm.request.url.query.all().forEach((param) => {
    params.push(`${param.key}=${param.value}`);
});

params.sort();
var hash = CryptoJS.MD5(params.join("")).toString();
```

But how can I do it in Paw?